# Glassfish 3 redirect all http requests to https

Tags: java, http, https, glassfish

I want to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPs. How can I do this?

I've already tried by editing default-web.xml file, but after that the Glassfish admin panel did not work.

I've added these lines to `default-web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>

   <web-resource-collection>

     <web-resource-name> **here i've added the website name** </web-resource-name>

     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

   </web-resource-collection>

   <user-data-constraint>

     <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>

   </user-data-constraint>

 </security-constraint>
```

app version : Glassfish 3

OS : Redhat 6

Comment: What exactly you have edited in default-web.xml file? If you can share your edited file.

Comment: It can be useful : http://www.antwerkz.com/port-unification-in-glassfish-3-part-1/

Comment: <security-constraint>

   <web-resource-collection>

     <web-resource-name> here i've add website name </web-resource-name>

     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

   </web-resource-collection>

   <user-data-constraint>

     <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>

   </user-data-constraint>

 </security-constraint>

Comment: @SunilKanzar I've tried that link. It doesnt work for me.

Comment: @Prashant i've added lines to answer.

Comment: @AmirDamirov please remove your answer and add it to the question.

Comment: @AmirDamirov glad you added required code but it should be added by editing your question and into it. And also delete the answer you posted.

Comment: @Prashant thank you for correcting.

I've added.

Comment: Amir, you need port unification, just go through this [blog](http://www.antwerkz.com/port-unification-in-glassfish-3-part-1/). I'm sure this will solve your problem.